# How to enable queries logs in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, logs, log

I'm running `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.46-MariaDB` in CentOS 6.7 server. I'm trying to get queries logged and I'm doing by redirecting log to files as shown below:

```
#/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 512M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

log-output = FILE

#General Query Log
general_log
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log

#Error Log
log_error               = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

#Slow Query Log
log-slow-queries
slow_query_log          = 1
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time         = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes

collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Before restart MySQL service I did run the following command to create each file and assign proper permissions:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/mysql && touch /var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log && touch /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log && touch /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log && chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/
```

I have restarted the MySQL daemon:

```
service mysql restart
```

After restart the MySQL server I can see the files but with 0 size so MySQL is not sending anything to those files. I did run the following query on MySQL console `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%'` and below is the result and as you may notice changes are not made at server:

```
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aria_checkpoint_log_activity              | 1048576                                                                                                      |
| aria_log_file_size                        | 1073741824                                                                                                   |
| aria_log_purge_type                       | immediate                                                                                                    |
| aria_sync_log_dir                         | NEWFILE                                                                                                      |
| back_log                                  | 50                                                                                                           |
| binlog_annotate_row_events                | OFF                                                                                                          |
| binlog_cache_size                         | 32768                                                                                                        |
| binlog_checksum                           | NONE                                                                                                         |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates   | OFF                                                                                                          |
| binlog_format                             | STATEMENT                                                                                                    |
| binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling         | ON                                                                                                           |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                    | 32768                                                                                                        |
| expire_logs_days                          | 0                                                                                                            |
| general_log                               | OFF                                                                                                          |
| general_log_file                          | pdone-prod.log                                                                                               |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1                                                                                                            |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog            | OFF                                                                                                          |
| innodb_log_block_size                     | 512                                                                                                          |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                    | 8388608                                                                                                      |
| innodb_log_file_size                      | 5242880                                                                                                      |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                 | 2                                                                                                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                 | ./                                                                                                           |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                | 1                                                                                                            |
| innodb_recovery_update_relay_log          | OFF                                                                                                          |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                                                                                                           |
| log                                       | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_bin                                   | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators           | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_error                                 | /var/lib/mysql/pdone-prod.pdi-inc.com.err                                                                    |
| log_output                                | FILE                                                                                                         |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes             | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_slave_updates                         | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_slow_filter                           | admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk |
| log_slow_queries                          | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_slow_rate_limit                       | 1                                                                                                            |
| log_slow_verbosity                        |                                                                                                              |
| log_warnings                              | 1                                                                                                            |
| max_binlog_cache_size                     | 18446744073709547520                                                                                         |
| max_binlog_size                           | 1073741824                                                                                                   |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                | 18446744073709547520                                                                                         |
| max_relay_log_size                        | 0                                                                                                            |
| relay_log                                 |                                                                                                              |
| relay_log_index                           |                                                                                                              |
| relay_log_info_file                       | relay-log.info                                                                                               |
| relay_log_purge                           | ON                                                                                                           |
| relay_log_recovery                        | OFF                                                                                                          |
| relay_log_space_limit                     | 0                                                                                                            |
| slow_query_log                            | OFF                                                                                                          |
| slow_query_log_file                       | pdone-prod-slow.log                                                                                          |
| sql_log_bin                               | ON                                                                                                           |
| sql_log_off                               | OFF                                                                                                          |
| sync_binlog                               | 0                                                                                                            |
| sync_relay_log                            | 0                                                                                                            |
| sync_relay_log_info                       | 0                                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What could be wrong here? Why logs are not being sent to those files?

**UPDATES**

**@rick-james**: I did check permissions by running:

```
# ls -ld /var/log/mysql/
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Nov 30 16:44 /var/log/mysql/
```

And apparently are good (777).

**@ypercube**: Below is the result of the command you want me to run.

```
# ls -l /var/log/mysql/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_query.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_slow.log
```

In first place all files was `chmod` as `644` but I change that to be `775` now result looks like:

```
# ls -l /var/log/mysql/
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_error.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_query.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mysql mysql 0 Nov 30 16:44 mysql_slow.log
```

But not change at all, logs are not beeing saved in those files. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally I found where the issue was! For some reason I delete `/etc/my.cnf` file (perhaps when I uninstall MySQL or something else) and that's the file including everything under `/etc/my.cnf.d` because of that changes don't take effect. My bad. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Check under `/var/log/mysql/` like your my.cnf says.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';` -- to see if the settings really took effect.

Is there a `/etc/my.cnf` file?

Look at the arguments on mysqld that is running to see if they override anything.

Did you restart mariadb?

Comment: Nop, there is nothing at that path, even `mysql` directory isn't created under `/var/ logs`. Yes, there is a /etc/my.cnf` with this content: `[client-server]
# include all files from the config directory
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d1`, how do I see the arguments? Yes I have restarted MariaDB and even the whole server

Comment: To do the `SHOW`, connect on the commandline "mysql" and execute the command.

Comment: You said `/var/log/mysql/`, not `/var/mysql/`, nor `/var/logs/mysql/`.

Comment: I have added `SHOW` command output to the main post but still not having that file, see the output of tail command: `tailf /var/log/mysql/mysql-general.log` result `tailf: cannot stat "/var/log/mysql/mysql-general.log": No such file or directory`

Comment: Are there are any related errors in the error file? If the user that the mysql service is running under, does not have write permission for  the `/var/log/mysql/` directory, it will show in the error file. And is there such a directory in the first place? What does `ls /var/log/mysql/` show?

Comment: Please provide `ls -ld /var/log/mysql/`

Comment: @RickJames I have updated the main post with new test case since I am running the same issue and can't find a reason or a fix. I did include the output for the command you leave me

Comment: @ypercube I have updated the main post with new test since I am running the same issue and can't find a reason or a fix. I did include the output for the command you leave me

Comment: @ypercube important I am not seeing issues at all at `pdone-prod.pdi-inc.com.err` the file where logs are going on by now

Comment: What "user" and "group" is mysqld running as?  What OS are you using?